# SET a1 WHERE a AND b1 WHERE b AND c1 WHERE c, etc

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I have a MySQL table with images data. My backend app is using a live sorting module (drag & drop images).

What I want is to update within a **single query** all sorted images **after** sorting process is done, instead of updating single query each time I drop image to a new position (I need to disable any connections while sorting).

As for now, I made this using a `foreach` loop. Compare two arrays - one that holds the original order of the files, and the second one that holds the new order. When the sorting is done it updates only the images with different order. But I'm not sure if the loop is a good place for firing multi-queries (with many images this could drastically overload app)

```
public function setSortFilesinSql($new_sort_arr)
{
    $sql = new sql();
    $sql->sqlConnect();
    foreach ($new_sort_arr as $key=>$value){
        if($this->_original_sort[$key] != $value){
            $sql->query("UPDATE images SET sort='".$key."' WHERE name='".$value."' AND full_path='".$this->path."'");
        }
    }
    $this->_original_sort = $new_sort_arr;
    $sql->disconnect();
}
```

Is there any way to "simlify/speedify" the whole process, or set this as a single query?

---

### EDIT

I've checked CASE clause like this:

```
public function setSortFilesinSql($new_sort_arr)
{
    $sql = new sql();
    $sql->sqlConnect();
    $sort_query = "UPDATE images SET sort = CASE CONCAT(full_path, '/', name)";
    foreach ($new_sort_arr as $key=>$value){
        if($this->_original_sort[$key] != $value){
            $sort_query .= "WHEN '".$this->path."/".$value."' THEN '".$key."' ";
        }
    }

    $sort_query .= "ELSE sort END CASE";
    $sql->query($sort_query);
    $this->_original_sort = $new_sort_arr;
    $sql->disconnect();

}
```

Query above gives me following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE'

Comment: I believe you're looking for the mysql "in" clause, yes?   update images where name in(comma,separated,list,of,names)?

Comment: I might be wrong, but this would not fire when I have to compare 2 columns (`name` and `full_path`), because there may be few the same `names` but with different `full_path`. At least I can't imagine how to  put the code together with `in` clause in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just write the SQL part, you can build it from PHP:

```
UPDATE images
SET sort = CASE name
    WHEN 'x' THEN 1
    WHEN 'y' THEN 2
    ...
    ELSE sort
    END
WHERE full_path='...';
```

Additionally you can filter the rows in the `WHERE` clause with `AND name in ('x', 'y')`. In this case you can save the *ELSE* part in the *CASE*.

If you want to use more than one column to identify your row, use this:

```
UPDATE images
SET sort = CASE CONCAT(full_path, '/', name)
    WHEN 'path/x' THEN 1
    WHEN 'path/y' THEN 2
    ...
    ELSE sort
    END
```

Comment: I got the error with CASE clause: _You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHERE full_path='full-images/''_

Comment: Check the code up there, and follow that. `CASE` is like `switch` statement, you can have different values based on *one value-expression*. It is NOT like `if - elseif`.

Comment: The [MySQL CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html) reference is here.

Comment: OK, I found the typo, updated the code. You don't need `CASE` after the `END`

Comment: Please look at my first post. I've updated the code with the CASE clause. I'm not sure what is wrong there.

Comment: Like I said, you don't need `CASE` after the `END`. The error message tells you exactly.

Comment: Yes! That was the extra `CASE` at the end of your code :) It works indeed. But how about performance of the `CASE` long query comparing it to few small queries? Is it worth to use `CASE` in my situation? Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33585/discussion-between-phillip100-and-camouflage)

Comment: If you are worrying about the performance, you should define a primary key on your table (say `id`), and use the `id` column instead of the `CONCAT()` expression. Also, it helps if you put the extra `id IN (...)` filter to the end of the query. With these boosts it will produce better performance than using `n` standalone updates, mainly because of the (lack of) communication overhead.